# Setting TypeConverter from another attribute

Tags: c#, properties, attributes

I have a particular TypeConvert that will get used on many properties that have other attributes. I'd like to replace this:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(LengthConverter))]
```

with something more concise/readable, like this:

```
[Meters]
```

Unfortunately, TypeConverterAttribute is sealed, so I can't just inherit it and set what I want by calling the base constructor.

Is there a way to do this?